# Clear git-credential-manager-core cached login

Tags: windows, git, git-credential-manager

Cannot clear the git-credential-manager-core cache

**it always show the last user**

[image]

1. Using Windows credentials Manager - no login regarding Git
2. Using the "Forget: option in Dialog not working
   [image]
3. Using "Erase" in Git Bash Not clearing
   [image]
4. Delete all Sign-In from Visual Studio
   [image]
5. delete all "%LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService"

any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You should try at command line by `git config --global --unset user.password`.

Please let me know if it worked.

Regards.

Comment: sorry . did not work

Answer (score 0):

Disable Git Credential Manager if you don’t use it.

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Comment: tried , did not work

Answer (score 0):

Do all above Steps - in original Question.
And  also clean all content using Internet Explorer
[image]